# LineGraph Labels

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I have a graph with labels on the edges:

```
ilGrafo=Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 6, 4 <-> 7,  6 <-> 7}, 
 EdgeLabels -> {1 <-> 2 -> "A", 1 <-> 3 -> "B", 2 <-> 3 -> "C", 
   3 <-> 4 -> "E", 4 <-> 5 -> "E", 4 <-> 6 -> "E", 4 <-> 7 -> "G", 6 <-> 7 -> "H"}]
```

I would like to obtain the `LineGraph[ilGrafo]` with the corresponding edge name on the vertices, but I am not able to find the way.

Comment: `LineGraph[#, EdgeLabels -> PropertyValue[#, EdgeLabels]] &[ilGrafo]`

Answer (score 2):

I guess that somone has to answer it.

```
ilGrafo=Graph[
  {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 6, 4 <-> 7, 6 <-> 7},
  EdgeLabels -> {1 <-> 2 -> "A", 1 <-> 3 -> "B", 2 <-> 3 -> "C", 3 <-> 4 -> "E", 
                 4 <-> 5 -> "E", 4 <-> 6 -> "E", 4 <-> 7 -> "G", 6 <-> 7 -> "H"}]
```

giving

[image: ilGrafo]

In order to keep the `EdgeLabels` while applying `LineGraph` you can use:

```
LineGraph[#, EdgeLabels -> PropertyValue[#, EdgeLabels]] &[ilGrafo]
```

giving

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
however the ilGrafo edge labels do not correspond  to the LineGraph vertex labels.

Answer (score 2):

I think the function should be like this:

```
LabeledLineGraph[graph_] :=  
Module[{m = IncidenceMatrix[graph], length = EdgeCount[graph]},  
AdjacencyGraph[(Transpose[m].m - 2 IdentityMatrix[length]),  
VertexLabels -> Thread@Rule[Range@length, EdgeList[graph]/.PropertyValue[graph,EdgeLabels]]]]
```

The result of `LabeledLineGraph[ilGrafo]` is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edge names and labels placed above and below the associated vertex in `LineGraph`:

```
labelF = SetProperty[VertexReplace[LineGraph[#, VertexLabels->"Name", ImagePadding -> 25],
  Thread[Range[EdgeCount @ #] -> (EdgeList[#])]], VertexLabels -> 
  (# -> Placed[{##}, {Above, Below}] & @@@ PropertyValue[#, EdgeLabels])]&;  

labelF @ ilGrafo
```

[image]